# Is it reasonable to have a network-mounted home dir but a local ~/.cache?

Tags: directory-structure, cache, home

I want to free up some space in my network-mounted home directory. I'm noticing that my `.cache` directory is very big. I was wondering whether I should replace it with a symlink, `~/.cache -> /machine_specific_data/myusername/cache`. That would mean that on each machine on the network I would have a perfectly distinct cache directory, but the rest of the files would be shared.

Will this work? Will I have conflicts? Will the local caches get thrashed due to changes in shared files?

PS - My operating system is Devuan GNU/Linux 4 (Chimaera).